# Automatic project build during system rebuild

Tags: nix, nixos

I have a `default.nix` script. Once launched (`nix-build`), it downloads and builds the project from github. How can I put this script in `configuration.nix` to build automatically during `nixos-rebuild` ?

```
buildGoModule rec{ 
    name = "hhh";
    version = "1.4";
    src = fetchGit{

      url = "";
       rev = "";
       allRefs = true;
    };
   vendorSha256 = "";
  
   proxyVendor = true;

    postInstall = ''
        `cp -rf $src/template/ $out/bin`  
    '';


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just do something like:
`import /path/to/default.nix {config, pkgs}`

Otherwise maybe: `pkgs.callPackage /path/to/default.nix {}`. I don't have a good understanding of how callPackage is different or when to use... But this might be helpful: https://summer.nixos.org/blog/callpackage-a-tool-for-the-lazy/

Answer (score 3):

There are various ways to incorporate a Nix derivation into your NixOS configuration.  Since you appear to be building an executable application, maybe what you want to do is put it into your [environment.systemPackages](https://search.nixos.org/options?show=environment.systemPackages) option so it will be on your PATH and you can easily run it from a shell.  In the end it should look something like:

```
environment.systemPackages = [ your_go_package ];
```

where `your_go_package` is the thing you wrote above (either directly, or stored in a variable).